# Flex 3: errorstring tooltip delay?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, tooltip

I've got a simple text input which I want to use the errorstring tooltip on, ie. when you assign a value to errorstring it colours the textinput red and shows an error tooltip when you hover the mouse over it.

This all works fine, but there is a long delay (maybe 10 seconds) between when the mouse is over the offending textinput and when the tooltip appears. Does anyone know how to influence this delay ? I've had a good look around, but can't find anything.

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found out that the TooltipManager influences these delays. For example:

```
ToolTipManager.showDelay = 0;// Display immediately.
ToolTipManager.hideDelay = 3000; // Hide after 3 seconds of being viewed.
```

Obvious really......